# Is gluten free diet a fad or does it have legitimate health reasons?

Tags: diet, health

So I know some people are allergic to gluten, so in that scenario, a gluten free diet makes sense.

However, I know a lot of people who goes on the gluten free diet and I know most of them are not allergic to gluten.

Are there any legitimate health reasons for a gluten free diet?

Comment: Some say so, some say so. When in doubt, try it for a month and see how you feel. That's the most reliable information you'll get. You're also off-topic, unfortunately.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to say.  "Try it for a month and see how you feel." ??!!  If I don't know much about crack cocaine, I wouldn't say that.

Comment: There's a difference between an addictive, destructive drug and a diet choice. She's saying that some people feel better on a gluten free diet, give it a try and see how you feel. Other than that, your question is off topic for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're getting more into diet than a fitness question, but [the evidence is pretty clear currently that "gluten insensitivity" either does not exist or cannot be tested for](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/is-gluten-the-new-candida/). The only scientifically determined problem with gluten is celiac disease. Everything past that is a mix of marketers taking advantage of the panic and misinformed people advocating the "try it and see" diet. Much like any other fad diet, including paleo, Atkins, etc, it can help people because junk food just happens to typically include gluten, but there is no real evidence for gluten insensitivity, just the gluten intolerance that leads to celiac disease.